# Wp вместо 404 страницы выдает редирект 301

Tags: wordpress

У меня проблема с сайтом на  wp  я
ввожу не существующий адрес и у меня происходит 301 редирект в htacces
ничего такого не прописано. Подскажите,пожалуйста, в чем проблема.   https://iambtl.ru/services/promfdgdfgdfgdfgdfgrvices/handymen/

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Где вы увидели, что происходит 301 редирект?

Comment: @АлексейМельников Изображение диагностики выложил

Comment: Если в htaccess ничего такого нет, может есть какие-то плагины? Часто бывает так, что плагины портят картину. Попробуйте по одному отключать плагины, которые могут к этому относится. Либо переименуйте папку /wp-content/plugins на  /wp-content/plugins1, так вы отключите все плагины. И можно будет посмотреть пропала ли проблема, чтобы понять откуда ноги растут

Comment: Спасибо, но не помогло. Я htacces выложил еще

Comment: А где? Что-то не вижу...

Answer (score 1):

Это не бага, это фича (с). ВП видит **правильный** слаг документа `handymen`  и пытается его выдать пользователю.

ЗЫ. А тег `php` тут совершенно [не нужен](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info).

> Используйте эту метку, если у вас возникли вопросы по применению данного языка или о самом языке.